# Trigger sbt `~` after rsync

Tags: scala, sbt, rsync

I'd like remote machine to run `sbt` task. The scenario is as follows:

- run `sbt ~compile` on remote machine
- edit source files locally
- launch `rsync` to update files on remote machine
- remote machine should trigger `compile` source changes

The last point does not work. What should I do to make it work?

Comment: Why not just ssh in and run compile?  You could put it in a shell script and have it still be automated.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: To save time on starnig `sbt`

Comment: What happens if you run it locally? This should work IMO, but maybe the files are not being monitored by sbt?

Comment: Locally works fine: if I change a file on a remote machine, then source-change triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few things to try:

1. Try using `ssh user@host "nohup sbt ~compile"`
2. Try a terminal multiplexer like `tmux` or `screen`. Login to remote, start the multiplexer, run command, and then detach.

Comment: screen and tmux doesn't work. nohup works strange. It refreshes not every time I update sorces. Why nohup way works? How can that be it refreshes not every time?

Comment: I am surprised that the multiplexer solution doesn't work. Have you ever tried running the `sbt ~compile` in one terminal while running `rsync` from another?

Comment: Neither nohup, nor screen, nor tmux are worknig. No, haven't tried to rsync changes with another terminal :) There is very similar problem with play-framework and vagrant: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/play-framework/uUlcDeMO1Ag/_9-PmRbSyNQJ.